# Import XML DB data to Solr

Tags: solr

I am using Oracle's XMLTYPE as a single column to store user profile. I can import varchar2 type into Solr using DataImportHandler but not the column has XMLType. It will report errors. How can I import it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand Oracle gives back to you a String that contains plain xml? In that case I can think of two options:

1. do as you are doing, but apply a [script transformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) and process the xml there to extract the information you need properly
2. do as you are doing, but apply a [custom transformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) that you develop in java